# Django Yandex Maps API

Tags: django, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, мне надо подключить модуль Яндекс для регистрации пользователей (указание адреса клиента). Не могу найти толковую документацию(

Comment: Согласно условиям бесплатного использования карт, использовать данные, полученные из карт, за пределами этих самых карт запрещено

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону https://dadata.ru/ и https://github.com/hflabs/dadata-py/ . Возможно поможет